# How to use the same URL Schemes to open two different iOS app

Tags: ios

I have some iOS app and I want to use the same URL schemes to open them from safari or other app, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is an entry that I write in this blog:
How to launch your Application from Safari
http://appleiostips.wordpress.com/2011/07/27/launch-app-from-safari/

You must open with XCode the file myapp-Info.plist . Then add a new kind of row called: URL Types,add an Item 0 inside. Inside the item add URL scheme. In this URL scheme write the name you what to register for your application. In this example we have used myapp .

Then when iOS finds a link to myapp://withsomestuff will launch the application and call the handleURL method inside your application delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*) application handleOpenURL:(NSURL*) url
Inside this method you can parse the url to obtain aditional parameters.

    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*) application handleOpenURL:(NSURL*) url{
    if (!url) return NO;
    NSString* urlString=[url absoluteString];
    NSLog(@”Received URL %@”,urlString);
    NSString *loginCmd=@”myapp://login?”;
    //Expects to receive myapp://login?user_name&password
    if ([urlString hasPrefix:loginCmd]){
        NSRange rangeAmp=[urlString rangeOfString:@"&"];
        if (rangeAmp.location>([loginCmd length]+1)){
            NSString* password=[urlString substringFromIndex:rangeAmp.location+1];
            NSRange userRange={[loginCmd length],rangeAmp.location-[loginCm length]};
            NSString* user=[urlString substringWithRange:userRange];
        }
    }
returnYES;
}
```

Comment: I can open a app from safari,but I want to use the same URL Schemes to open different apps ,how can I do?

Comment: huangshouwu - just go:  '[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openUrl:url]'